# Python requests - POST data from a file

Tags: python, file, python-requests

I have used curl to send POST requests with data from files.

I am trying to achieve the same using python requests module. Here is my python script

```
import requests
payload=open('data','rb').read()
r = requests.post('https://IP_ADDRESS/rest/rest/2', auth=('userid', 'password'), data=payload , verify=False)
print r.text
```

Data file looks like below

```
'ID' : 'ISM03'
```

But my script is not POSTing the data from file. Am I missing something here.

In Curl , I used to have a command like below

```
Curl --data @filename -ik -X POST 'https://IP_ADDRESS/rest/rest/2'
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You do not need to use `.read()` here, simply stream the object directly. You do need to set the Content-Type header explicitly; `curl` does this when using `--data` but `requests` doesn't:

```
with open('data','rb') as payload:
    headers = {'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    r = requests.post('https://IP_ADDRESS/rest/rest/2', auth=('userid', 'password'),
                      data=payload, verify=False, headers=headers)
```

I've used the open file object as a context manager so that it is also auto-closed for you when the block exits (e.g. an exception occurs or `requests.post()` successfully returns).

Comment: How is it, that you always seem to answer even the hardest python questions?

Comment: Don't believe everything I post.. There was an error in the first revision there.

Comment: @MartijnPieters thanks for the reply.. I still couldn't POST the data from the file. If I use the values directly in the script it works. ex- payload={ 'ID' : 'ISM03' }. But when I have the contents in a file and use as you have mentioned, I couldn't update. Do I need to change the format in the input file ?

Comment: `curl` expects the data file to be properly encoded *already*, and so does `requests`. I assumed you wanted it posted *as is*, just like `curl --data @filename` would do.

Comment: When you use `payload = {'ID' : 'ISM03'}` you are creating a python dictionary instead, and that then is encoded in the right format (`ID=ISM03` in this specific case). If you put *that* into the data file it'll work in both curl and `requests`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Great piece of information... thanks . Able to achieve it now.

Comment: does `requests` close the file for me after posting or should I close it myself?

Comment: @khrf: It doesn't close it, no. Updated to use the file object as a context manager to ensure it is closed.