# python-requests equivalent to curl's --data-binary?

Tags: python, rest, python-requests

Curl has an option to send a file as is with the [--data-binary option](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#--data-binary).

When testing the [Qualys WAS API](http://www.qualys.com/docs/WAS_API_User_Guide.pdf), the following curl command works:

```
curl -u "username:password" -H "content-type: text/xml" -X "POST" --data-binary @- "https://qualysapi.qualys.com/qps/rest/3.0/search/was/webapp" < post.xml
```

post.xml:

```
<ServiceRequest><filters><Criteria operator="CONTAINS" field="name">PB - </Criteria></filters></ServiceRequest>
```

Using Python's requests module, I keep receiving a HTTPError: 415 Client Error: Unsupported Media Type.

```
import requests
url = 'https://qualysapi.qualys.com/qps/rest/3.0/search/was/webapp'
payload = '<ServiceRequest><filters><Criteria operator="CONTAINS" field="name">PB - </Criteria></filters></ServiceRequest>'
headers = {'X-Requested-With': 'Python requests', 'Content-type': 'application/json'}
r = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers, auth=('username', 'password'))
```

When trying to submit file files parameter, it also ended in a 415 error.

```
import requests
url = 'https://qualysapi.qualys.com/qps/rest/3.0/search/was/webapp'
payload = '<ServiceRequest><filters><Criteria operator="CONTAINS" field="name">PB - </Criteria></filters></ServiceRequest>'
headers = {'X-Requested-With': 'Python requests', 'Content-type': 'application/json'}
r = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers, auth=('username', 'password'))
```

The reason I'm setting this up is to incorporate this into the [qualysapi Python package](https://github.com/paragbaxi/qualysapi/).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python requests - POST data from a file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16145116/python-requests-post-data-from-a-file)

Comment: Your question title is rather misleading; your problem lies with the headers, not with how to emulate `--data-binary` with `requests`. The dupe I linked to *does* ask that question.

Comment: And judging from your `payload` contents and your `Content-type` header, my immediate response to your posted answer below is *Yeah, duh*. :-D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the headers I was supposed to have is

```
headers = {'X-Requested-With': 'Python requests', 'Content-type': 'text/xml'}
```