# Post string as FORMDATA in python

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to replicate this cURL onliner:

```
curl -i -XPOST 'http://httpbin.org/post?db=data' --data-binary 'files,host=server10,folder=max value=0.64 1434055562121200000'
```

to python with the help of python-requests.

I've tried:

```
import requests
payload = {'files,host=server10,folder=max value=0.64 1434055562121200000':'\n'}
or payload = {'files,host':'server10,folder=max value=0.64 1434055562121200000'}
or {'files,host=server10,folder=max value=0.64 1434055562121200000':''}
or {'files,host=server10,folder=max value=0.64 1434055562121200000'}

r = requests.post('http://httpbin.org/post?db=data', data=payload)
```

I need some pointers or help to get past this snag, because it's possible right?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17680688/python-requests-equivalent-to-curls-data-binary

Answer (score 1):

Answering my self.

```
import requests
url = 'http://10.10.10.10:8086/write?db=data'
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
payload = "cpu,host=server01,region=us-west value=0.64 1434055562000000000\n"
r = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers)
```

With this, posting to influxdb via python works the same as the above cURL onliner.

Comment: Thanks, helped me a lot.  Couldn't find the right header to use here.