# Python's Requests library adds tags to PDF, which breaks API

Tags: python, pdf, python-requests

I am using Python's Requests library to POST a PDF to a document store, the uploaded PDF is thereafter used in a signature process. However when uploading the PDF using Python (in stead of CURL) the signing environment doesnt work. On comparing different files, I found out that Requests adds some data to the PDF:

```
--ca9a0d04edf64b3395e62c72c7c143a5
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="LoI.pdf"; filename="LoI.pdf"

%%Original PDF goes here%%

--ca9a0d04edf64b3395e62c72c7c143a5--
```

This data is accepted perfectly fine by different PDF readers, but not by the Signature API. Is there a way to prevent Requests from adding this data to the PDF? I used the following code:

```
myfile = request.FILES['myfile']
url = %%documentstoreURL%%
resp = requests.request('post', url, files={myfile.name:myfile}, headers={'Content-Type':'application/pdf'}, auth=(%%auth details%%))
```

Thanks!

Comment: There is nothing added to the file. What you see is the file in multipart MIME encoding for transport. The API does not seem to support this standard way of encoding. So what else does it accept?

Comment: What curl command are you using, that works?

Comment: @KlausD. if I download the PDF from the documentstore and then open it with Notepad++ it still shows these "tags". So maybe it is indeed not processed well at the receiving end?

Comment: mwchase,

curl -u %%auth_details%% -k --data-binary @mydocument.pdf -H "Content-Type: application/pdf" https://%%documentstoreURL%%

Answer (score 0):

You're sending the file as binary data with curl, but attaching it in requests.

I read over the source code, and I believe `resp = requests.request('post', url, data={myfile.name:myfile}, headers={'Content-Type':'application/pdf'}, auth=(%%auth details%%))` (`data` instead of `files`) will avoid the multipart encoding.

At the very least, it should be differently broken.

Comment: Thanks! This almost solved it. It put me on the right track :). I posted the final working solution.

Answer (score 0):

Being guided in the right direction, I found a working solution based on [Python requests - POST data from a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16145116/python-requests-post-data-from-a-file)

In the end I did it as follows:

```
 myfile = request.FILES['myfile']
 payload = request.FILES['myfile'].read()
 headers = {'content-type': 'application/pdf'}
 url = "%%DocumentServiceURL"
 r = requests.post(url, auth=(%%auth_details%%), data=payload, verify=False, headers=headers)
```