# Do I need to use a with statement when sending multipart form data in requests?

Tags: python, python-requests, with-statement

In Python's `requests` [documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/), it suggests sending multipart form data like so:

> Requests makes it simple to upload Multipart-encoded files:

```
>>> url = 'http://httpbin.org/post'
>>> files = {'file': open('report.xls', 'rb')}

>>> r = requests.post(url, files=files)
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22567306/python-requests-file-upload) shows the same behavior. However, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16145116/python-requests-post-data-from-a-file) by the same author uses a `with` statement:

```
with open('data','rb') as payload:
    headers = {'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    r = requests.post('https://IP_ADDRESS/rest/rest/2', auth=('userid', 'password'),
                      data=payload, verify=False, headers=headers)
```

My intuition is that I should always use a `with` statement when using files; do I need it in this case or not? To be extra clear, I am *not* looking for advice as to whether or not to use `with`. I am specifically referring to the interaction with the `requests` library, and if I can omit the `with` statement as the docs imply.

Comment: I think using `with` is a way to automatically close the connection you opened in your `with`-statement. You can also do it without `with`, but then you need to close the connection explicitly, like `payload.close()`. I think.

Comment: @downvoter care to comment?

Comment: @Ares I'm not the downvoter but that person likely did so because this is an opinion-based question.

Comment: @TylerH I should clarify; I'm asking about the interaction between requests and `with`, not looking for an opinion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tl;dr: Your intuition is right.

---

Without a `with` statement (or an explicit `payload.close()` call), you're not closing the file.

Of course it's always *possible* that some function you call, passing the file as an argument, might `close` that file. But in general, they won't; and, in particular, `requests.post` doesn't. (Since that's pretty rare and unusual behavior, it would probably be documented if a function did that. But if you need to be absolutely sure, you can always test it—call the function and then check `f.closed`—or read the source.)

So, what happens if you don't close it? It just sits there open until the garbage collector deletes the file object. When does that happen? Well, you have a global variable named `files` that holds a dict that holds the file object. So the file object is accessible all the way until you quit the program. It *never* becomes garbage, so it never gets deleted, so the file never gets closed, until you `exit`.

Since you aren't writing anything to the file, this doesn't result in anything horrible like unflushed data sitting around in a buffer when you expected it to be on disk.

But it does mean you're wasting resources. The OS kernel has to keep some kind of structure for every open file, and the the process needs some other thing to reference that kernel structure. If you open thousands of files without closing them, eventually, one of those tables fills up, and the next time you try to open a file, you get an error about having too many files open.

And the kinds of programs that do a lot of work with `requests` tend to be exactly the kinds of programs that need to work with thousands of files, so this can be a real problem.

So, do you *need* a `with` statement here? Maybe not. But you definitely *want* one.

Comment: The footnote is the key information for me; I know how `with` works, but it was unclear to me given the number of reputable examples that don't use it if `requests` does or does not close the resource for me.

Comment: @Ares OK, I edited the answer to make the footnote part of the main answer, and to expand on it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Using a `with` statement handles closing resources for you. You should use this to properly handle external resources.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation is just trying to demonstrate how the `files` parameter works, without worrying too much about whether the file gets closed. A better example would be

```
with open('report.xls', 'rb') as f:
    r = requests.post(url, files={'file': f})
```