# Upload an image to an endpoint, where the image is sourced as a URI

Tags: python

I'm trying to post an image to an API, where it image is a URI supplied by another service:

```
import requests

input_data = {
    "employeeId": 123,
    "picture_uri": 'https://mw1.google.com/crisisresponse/icons/un-ocha/cluster_CCCM_100px_icon_bluebox.png'
}

# retrieve image from URI
r = requests.get(input_data['picture_uri'])

# create dictionary
file = {'photo': r.content}

uri = f"https://api.bamboohr.com/api/gateway.php/subdomain/v1/employees/{input_data['employeeId']}/photo"

response = requests.post(uri, auth=('account','password'), files=file)

print(response.status_code) # 400
```

What am I missing?

** edit **

Documentation indicates that the POST needs to be a `multipart/form-data`: https://documentation.bamboohr.com/reference/upload-employee-photo-1

Comment: Are there other details included in the response besides 400? Like a verbose description of why it was considered `400 Bad Request`?

Comment: @CoryKramer, the response object's `reason` is 'Bad Request'.  I don't see any other incidications.

Answer (score 2):

The `files` parameter can't directly be the bytes of the data. It has to be a file-pointer-like object. So you'd need to either save the file or pipe it through `io.BytesIO` and use the [tuple version of `files`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22567429/1431750) to give it a name:

```py
files = {'file': ('profile.png', io.BytesIO(r.content), 'image/png')}
reponse = requests.post(uri, auth=('account','password'), files=files)
```

Or better yet, [use the `data` parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16145232/1431750):

```py
headers = {'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}  # can skip this?
reponse = requests.post(uri, auth=('account','password'),
                        data=r.content, headers=headers)
```

Edit: If it's supposed to be `multipart/form-data` then the field names need to match with what they expect. More in the [requests toolbelt docs](https://toolbelt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user.html#multipart-form-data-encoder).

Comment: The first option worked, but the second one did not (with or without that header or `multipart/form-data`).

Comment: In the first version, what would happen if the file is a JPG?

Comment: I think no difference if it's a .JPG or .JPEG. Just a different mimetype `image/jpeg` (note jpeg, not jpg for the mimetype)

Comment: For the 2nd version, if it's supposed to be `multipart/form-data` then the field names need to match with what they expect. More in the [requests toolbelt docs](https://toolbelt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user.html#multipart-form-data-encoder).

Answer (score 0):

Per [documentation](https://documentation.bamboohr.com/reference/update-employee) your request should go to the endpoint `f"https://api.bamboohr.com/api/gateway.php/subdomain/v1/employees/{input_data['employeeId']}/`.

It also seems to overwrite the existing data, so I'd recommend getting
`https://api.bamboohr.com/api/gateway.php/{companyDomain}/v1/employees/{id}/`

and then posting `{**old_data, 'photo': r.content}`

Comment: The photos endpoint: https://documentation.bamboohr.com/reference/upload-employee-photo-1